# HTML img Why can't I load the local image with relative path, but copy the image to the same directory to display it?

Tags: html

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpTvi.png)

[running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL8dj.png)

HTML img Why can't I load the local image with relative path, but copy the image to the same directory to display it?

Comment: The path is based on the root of the web server, not your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because like this path will work `localhost:3000/myimage.jpg` whle this does not `./myimage.jpg`

You path should be **`/resources/image/t1.jpg`**

Comment: The problem is solved, the required path is: JavaLearning\resources\image\t1.jpg

Comment: Okay glad to help